# compare javascript time with php time

Tags: php, javascript, localtime

I'm working on a restaurant site and I have specific ordering hours. How do I compare a preset time-range with the current visitor's time?

Also I need to set this preset time-range through a form.

Thanks

edit:

I tried to explode the date numbers multiply them and compare but I'm not sure how reliable it is. Other than this I can't ask for the hours, I need to get them with javascript.

Also more exactly I need to let the client change the ordering hours in future.

edit 2: Can't I just compare times in php, a preset time-range with the current time and ditch the JavaScript?

Comment: Better not count on JavaScript but instead let the user choose his/her time zone then add the time offset server side.

Comment: As there has been said, careful while using javascript time, if the client browser's computer has a incorrect date, it could bring errors into your system.

Comment: You can detect user's location timezone according to the IP address in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always manipulate [Unix]timestamps in PHP comfortably. Take a look at PHP's `strtotime()` function.

You should be able to use it in a way that suits your current needs!

Answer (score 0):

When you get the DateTime object, in most languages, you can get it with the timezone offset. In Javascript you can use the UTC date to compare items.

Check this out [MDN DateTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Be sure that the full DateTime object with timezone offset is given, should that be from PHP to JavaScript or other way round.

I also recommend that the final check be done on server side (i.e.: in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript method `Date.getTime()` return timestamp value in milliseconds, php `time()` in seconds, you can reduce both values to second and compare them. 
Are your clients share same Time Zone?